# Determining monotonic behavior of a number in C

Tags: c

I want to write a simple program that determines whether the number the user inputs is increasing, strictly increasing, etc. etc.

To solve this I want to break up each digit and see if they are always getting smaller or not, etc. 
How do I break up the input into separate digits using scanf function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One has to wonder why you're not getting the input as integers in the first place (`%llu` perhaps?) - this would make comparisons so much easier. However, you could get each line from the user via `fgets` and then parse each character.

Since you mention you want to read large numbers:

```
int64_t num;
scanf("%"PRId64, &num);
```

Or maybe:

```
intmax_t num;
scanf("%jd", &num);
```

Comment: i'm using %f. My input can be up to 9 digits so I can't use %c or %d

Comment: the number I can get is at most 9 digits and is always whole and real. there might be a +/- though. I haven't learned intmax_t or int64_t yet...

Comment: I can't use these functions I'm not familiar with them. I can only use scanf and the most basic c operators

Comment: i'm learning from the beginning so can only use what i've learned so far. this problem is supposed to be solvable in this way

Comment: @nofe So `fgets` isn't in the beginning ?

Answer (score 0):

For reading single character use `%c`.

```
char digit;
scanf("%c", &digit);
```

You can also read whole number into char*

```
char number[100];
scanf("%s", number);
```

and you can access k-th digit by `number[k] - '0'`.

Comment: if i use a string of %c like: scanf("%c%c%c%c%c%c%c",&a,&b,&c,&d,&e,&f,&g) how can the computer know if all of the variables got a character or if the user only typed in 3 digits, for example?

Comment: I thought you wanted to read digits in a loop, until first white space.

Comment: no not in a loop, the user inputs any whole number up to 9 digits and then presses enter

Comment: %s - String of characters. This will read subsequent characters until a whitespace is found (whitespace characters are considered to be blank, newline and tab). But if numbers are up to 9 digits than cnicutar answer is best.